# Explanation of the ending of Frozen Day

Tags: plot-explanation, frozen-day

I recently watched [Frozen Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0756359/), an Israel movie where a woman survives a suicide bombing. She later visits the hospital and identified her friend who is in a coma. She started living in his apartment and soon everybody started to refer to her by the name of her hospitalized friend.

After a series of events she revisits the club where the bombing happened and see herself in front of her.

So is she in the coma or is her friend?

Answer (score 1):

From the last scene seems to me clear that she is in coma and all what happened after the bombing was in her imagination or a dream.